# calculation in postgresql function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to create function that serves as replacement for postgresql sum function in my query.

query itself it LOOONG and something like this

`SELECT .... sum(tax) as tax ... from (SUBQUERY) as bar group by id;`

I want to replace this sum function with my own which alters the end value by tax calculation.

So I created pgsql function like this:

```
DECLARE
  v double precision;
BEGIN
  IF val > 256 THEN
    v := 256;
  ELSE
    v := val;
  END IF;
  RETURN (v*0.21)/0.79;
END;
```

That function uses double precision as input. Using this function gives me error though:

```
column "bar.tax" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

So I tried to use double precision[] as input type for function - in that case the error was telling me that there was no postgresql function matching the name and given input type.

So is there a way to replace sum function in my query by using pgsql functions or not - I don't want to change any other parts of my query unless I really, Really, REALLY have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into [CREATE AGGREGATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-createaggregate.html) for aggregate functions. And in your expression you can do something like `sum(LEAST(tax,256)*21/79)` if I read you right.

Comment: allright. Thanks. You even answered my question twice offering an alternative. Awesome :)